# slide hover on navbar elements as you scroll down the page

Tags: jquery

I have a navbar with 6 different list elements like home,about etc.
I want each of this li elements to hover as we scroll down through all the sections.
I have used isVisible function which tells me if a section is visible in viewport or not....its working but at a time two list elements are having hover effect whenever both the sections are visible at the same time...How to fix this..How can I make only one list element to hover at a time even if two sections are in viewport?

following is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $.fn.isVisible = function() {

    var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
      rect.bottom >= 0 &&
      rect.right >= 0 &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight ||     document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }; 



  $(window).scroll(function(){

    if(("#aboutus").isVisible())
    {
      $(".aboutL").addClass("hoverEffect");
    } 
    else{
      $(".aboutL").removeClass("hoverEffect");
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Save if one of your elements has the effect already assigned, and make use of this value when deciding to open the next one: Something like this

```
var oneElementHasHoverEffect = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if(("#aboutus").isVisible())
       {
             if(oneElementHasHoverEffect == 0){
                  $(".aboutL").addClass("hoverEffect");
                  oneElementHasHoverEffect = 1;
             }
       }else{
            $(".aboutL").removeClass("hoverEffect");
              oneElementHasHoverEffect = 0;
        }

    if(("#home").isVisible())
       {
             if(oneElementHasHoverEffect == 0){
                  $(".homeL").addClass("hoverEffect");
                  oneElementHasHoverEffect = 1;
              }
       }else{
            $(".homeL").removeClass("hoverEffect");
              oneElementHasHoverEffect = 0;
        }

});
```

Comment: I had a little logical error there... I changed it a bit and now it should work better...

Comment: while scrolling down this works perfectly fine but when scrolling up again,there are two menus getting that effect simultaneously for a short duration.....So its not working smoothly while scrolling up..how can i fix this?

Comment: Strange... It shouldn't behave different when scrolling up or down... It's the same event... Can't explain. Perhaps you have a little mistake in your code, Did you create a jsFiddle for this? Then I could check...